# Haw to make ActionBar full width at large screens (tablet)?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

At my app i use ActionBar using AppCompat v7. I notice that on devices is something like padding on the left and on the right of ActionBar (white spaces). I have fixed that using that solution:

```
<resources>

<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="AppTheme"
    parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
    <!--<item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>-->
</style>
```

Everything looks ok at my cell phone (5 inches) but at large screens like tablets the problem still exists... why?

Comment: use use toolbar...!!!

Comment: so I have to rebuild my app? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I think using toolbar is the answer but if someone don't want to rebuild an app here is (less elegant) solution:

use:

```
ab.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_main);

Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) ab.getCustomView().getParent();
parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
parent.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00A0D1"));
```

instead of using

```
<item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
```

in style.xml

that "strange" padding is still there but have the same color like ActionBar.
Now Everything looks fine even on large screens.